# Extjs .submit method not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to upload a file using ExtJS using `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('fileUploadPanelTooling')[0].submit({//code})`.

My code is working on chrome but it is not working on Internet Explorer, I tried to solve this problem and found that on IE `API` is not hitting but it is hitting in Chrome.

**Code:**

```
var url = x.getWebServicePath()+'/APIADDRESS.do';

Ext.ComponentQuery.query('fileuploadpanel')[0].submit({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
    success: function(form,response) { },
    failure: function(form,response) { },
    callback: function(success, response) { },
});
```

is anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Can you post code of your fileuploadpanel ?

Comment: It is in this fiddle, I have changed name from `fileuploadpanel` to `fileuploadpanelSomething` https://jsfiddle.net/9hduhkrm/1/

Comment: I missed to include, I am getting `You're trying to decode invalid JSON` error on IE.